# why does posting to facebook page yield "user hasn't authorized the application"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have read the fb docs and written code to publish a message to a facebook "page", however I am getting an error that I don't expect to see:

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Here's what I've done:

- I set up a facebook application, which provides my `APP_ID` and
  `APP_SECRET`.
- I set up a test facebook "page". Let us refer to its fb id as `PAGE_ID`.
- Used OAuth to get a `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` with scope "publish_actions,manage_pages" for the user. I accepted the permissions requested by my app when redirected to the facebook auth page.
- I did a GET on `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts` using the `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`, and I get back a list of pages I administrate, including the one I want to post to.

This block of data for my page looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Community", 
      "name": "My Generic Test Page", 
      "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
      "id": PAGE_ID, 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }, 
    ....
  ]
}
```

Then I use the `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` to post a message to the page:

- I did a POST on `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed` with a field `message` equal to `This is a test post.`

Facebook returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Using the [token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token), I can confirm that my `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` is valid, and has scopes: `manage_pages` and `publish_actions`.

Where am I missing authorizing the application? Do I need additional scopes? Did I miss clicking something on the facebook authorization screen? Is there a setting on the app I am missing? After days of debugging this, I must be blind to the problem. :-|

Comment: can you please share your code i am getting exact same error ? Or can you please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434951/unable-to-post-to-facebook-page-javascript#40434951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`status_update` is not used anymore. To publish on pages, I had to use both `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`.

Answer (score 27):

You should add permission called **status_update**, for example

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Fdisplay%3Dpage&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=status_update&from_login=1&m_sess=1&rcount=1

[image]

and i'm able post to page i liked with the access token i get just now:
[image]

If you want to post as the admin of the page, you're require both **manage_pages and status_update** permissions, for example

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Fdisplay%3Dpage&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=manage_pages%2Cstatus_update&from_login=1&m_sess=1&rcount=1

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Yes! "status_update" was the permission I was missing. Thank you. Now why can't I find any mention of "status_update" among all the facebook docs about permissions? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/

Comment: I filed an issue with FB about the missing docs (or otherwise a bug). https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/289826861149962

Comment: @broc.seib If you visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, click the "Get access token" button, then you can found "status_update" under "Extended Permissions" tab. The official documentation is not always complete and up to date.

Comment: @林果皞 As of today with v2.2, there is no `status_update` permission available to me in the Extended Permissions tab.

Comment: @iain You now need the publish_pages permission for 2.3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Downvoting because this answer isn't an option that I can see in Facebook Graph API 4.x

Comment: @AndrewSmiley Are u kidding to downvote ? The version of Graph API is only v1.0 when i posted the answer. Do you expect the answer is still valid for Graph API v100 ?

Comment: @林果皞 can you please share the code for javascript i am getting exact same error or can you please have a look at this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434951/unable-to-post-to-facebook-page-javascript#40434951

Answer (score 2):

Well, this seems to be a common mistake that most of us make while trying to do an activity in social netwroks. Before trying to put up an open graph action,You need to set the permissions in your initial authorization request . By default you only gain 'read-only' access to their basic information.
Settintg up permisson at teh time of authetication is a must for Facebook and LinkedIn APIs..

See the `public_actions` section in [Facebook open graph permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/) here and make relevant changes in the authorization code , and get your issue solved.

Comment: In my third step, I had successfully requested (and been granted) permissions "publish_actions" and "manage_pages". What other permissions are required to post a message to a facebook page?

Comment: I'd take a working code sample in about any language. I happen to be using java (using Scribe and RestFB). I've also distilled the problem down enough that I can reproduce it using just the GraphExplorer poking the raw HTTP API. So it would fit that this is a matter of getting the right permissions lined up.

Comment: I *did* set permissions in my initial request. I'll ask again: *Which* permissions are needed besides "publish_actions" and "manage_pages"?

Comment: If you have already set the permissions, you get this error because you are not correctly switching the request to post, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522249/1756131)

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to get a valid token and check permissions was via the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) BUT while Facebook's documentation is *extensive* it is not always the easiest to follow.

*In the explorer you have to look at both:*

1. **The Application** Currently at the top and quite subtle, I missed this for ages.
2. **Get Token Dropdown** What you click to get a Token, when you click the arrow you can choose pages and other items you have access to for selecting a token for.