# Cannot obtain page access token through an app that is granted the manage_pages permission

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to develop a PHP application that will let me make new posts on my Pages automatically, through a cronjob, while I am offline and not logged into Facebook at all. I'm aware that the **offline_access** permission has long been gone, but the [Removal of offline_access permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) article clearly states the following:

> **Scenario 5: Page Access Tokens**
>
> When a user grants an app the **manage_pages** permission, the app is able
>   to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by
>   querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration
>   enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this
>   endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access
>   token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a
>   long-lived user access token, querying the **[User ID]/accounts** endpoint
>   will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that
>   a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring
>   user access token obtained through the deprecated **offline_access**
>   permission.

... which made me think that an automated PHP solution like what I had in mind was indeed possible to engineer. So I went ahead and created a new Application and granted the **manage_pages** permission, as well as the **publish_actions** permission.

However my code:

```
<?php
require_once("sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = MY_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = MY_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$accountID = MY_ACCOUNT_ID;
$pages = $facebook->api("/$accountID/accounts/");
var_dump($pages);
?>
```

...returns the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required
>   to request this resource.

What am I doing wrong?

Even more confusing - at the very same time, this piece of code here, posts a status update to my Wall without a problem (and I'm still not logged into Facebook or anything)

```
<?php
require_once("sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = MY_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = MY_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $config['appId'] .
                "&client_secret=" . $config['secret'] .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = str_replace('access_token=','',file_get_contents($token_url));


$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $app_token,
    'message'       => 'test post via app access token'
);
$accountID = MY_ACCOUNT_ID;
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$accountID/feed", "post", $args);
?>
```

...and if I do

```
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$myPageID/feed", "post", $args);
```

...instead, I get:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this action

**THE SOLUTION**

With the kind help of *Mr. Mohammed Alaghbari*, I was able to make reasonable progress on this issue and eventually ended up coming to a solution.

As he suggested, I needed to generate a User Access Token first, issuing a request like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

In order to retrieve the actual Page Access Token and post to the page. So I realized that as I log in through the Login Link generated by the PHP SDK, a USER_ACCESS_TOKEN is stored for me inside a $_SESSION variable. I took that token, issued a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`, retrieved the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN and used it in order to successfully post a test message to my Page.

However, I then logged out and issued a `session_destroy();` To my surprise, the minute I did that, my code started throwing the `A user access token is required to request this resource.` exception again. I was very frustrated.

Then, I decided to manually request `https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/accounts/?MY_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` and see what happens. To my even bigger surprise - the GRAPH API accepted the USER_ACCESS_TOKEN and returned all valid Page Tokens. I was very frustrated why I was getting an exception in the SDK, but no errors when I issue a request directly to the GRAPH API, so I decided to start debugging **base_facebook.php**. The PHP SDK I'm using is Version 3.2.2.

After hours of searching, it turned out that this code located at line 899 of **base_facebook.php** throws the exception without a reason (sort of)

```
if (!isset($params['access_token'])) {
  $params['access_token'] = $this->getAccessToken();
}
```

When I commented the line `$params['access_token'] = $this->getAccessToken();` out, my PHP SDK requests started returning valid tokens again.

Weird. I'm wondering if this is a bug in the PHP SDK, or a problem with my code. My final code looks roughly like this:

```
<?php
require_once("sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = MY_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = MY_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$token = MY_USER_TOKEN; // extracted from $_SESSION

$response = $facebook->api("/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/accounts/?access_token=$token");

// code that extracts the page token from $response goes here

$args = array(
    'access_token'  => MY_PAGE_TOKEN,
    'message'       => 'test post via app access token'
);

$post_id = $facebook->api("/MY_PAGE_ID/feed", "post", $args); // It works!!
?>
```

**EDIT #2**

After some further testing, it turned out that instead of commenting out line 899, you could just revise

```
$facebook->api("/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/accounts/?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```

to

```
$facebook->api("/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/accounts/", 'get', array('access_token' => 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maringtr,

To interact with page you need to use Page Access Token (Check Access Token Types: [Access Token Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/))

**Types Are: User Access Token, Page Access Token, App Access Token**

Which can be generated with graph like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The above graph will give you a list of Pages you manage with there details (Page Name, ID, Access Token)

You can test the Page Access token to fetch Your Page Feeds with Graph (Replace `Page_ID` with your page id and `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` with Page Access token generated from the above Graph )

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=Testing
```

For more Information and Examples : [Log In as Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for you response. The problem was that I couldn't obtain a Page Access Token programatically, because I was getting a `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.` when trying to request `$pages = $facebook->api("/$accountID/accounts/");` in order to obtain the page token. I figured out I could take the user token recorded in the $_SESSION variable upon login, then logout, but keep using it in to perform `$facebook->api("/$accountID/accounts/");` and obtain the page token. I was able to post to my page with the obtained token. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm, actually it seems to have stopped working after logout. I just destroyed my session using `session_destroy()` and now I get the same error.

Comment: Welcome My Friend, You can use refresh Token to refresh your access token after it becomes invalid,,, Did you generate a user access token before generating Page access token?

Comment: Thank you Mohammed, I've posted a full response to you in my original post (it was too long to post as a comment response)

Answer (score 0):

Please grant **status_update**, as i've explained here [why does posting to facebook page yield "user hasn't authorized the application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application/15943045#15943045)

Comment: I granted the **status_update** permission, but the `Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action` error remains.