# Facebook SDK for Android - post to page feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to deal with Facebook SDK on Android.
For now, posting to user's feed (me/feed) is done and working properly.
After user authenticating, my application receives manage_pages permission, and propose user to save groups he have admin rights to.

```
private void requestPermissions() {
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions",
            "manage_pages");
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                myActivity, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
};
```

Later user can choose group to post. After that, application makes request to get page access token and starts posting:

```
private void postToGroup() {
    if (session != null) {
        Log.d("FB", "groupToken request!");
        Request myreq = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/accounts",
                new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.d("FB", "received token");
                        GraphObject obj = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject json = obj.getInnerJSONObject();
                        try {
                            String token = null;
                            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
                            Log.d("FB", frag.getAcc().getLogin());
                            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject acc = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
                                Log.d("FB", acc.getString("id"));
                                if (acc.getString("id").equals(
                                        frag.getAcc().getLogin())) {
                                    Log.d("FB",
                                            "token finded! "
                                                    + acc.getString("access_token"));
                                    token = acc.getString("access_token");
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("FB", token);
                            executeRequest(token);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                });
        myreq.executeAsync();
    } else {
        Log.d("FB", "Session is closed");
    }
}
```

Here's executeRequest method:

```
private void executeRequest(String token) {

        postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", postTitle);
        postParams.putString("message", frag.getContent());
        postParams.putString("access_token", token);
        request = new Request(session, frag.getAcc()
                .getLogin() + "/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST,
                callback);

    Log.d("FB", "Executing post request");
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

And callback for it:

```
private Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.d("FB", "get response!");
        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error == null) {
            JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject();
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                Log.d("FB", postId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("FB error", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("FB error", error.getErrorMessage()); //HERE I'M RECEIVING AN ERROR
        }
    }

};
```

And after post attempt i'm receiving error "**The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**".
Please, help me to deal with correct request in this case. Or, maybe, i should try to make raw Graph curl request? I'm scratching out my head about 2 weeks with this, but the only information i finded is "you must use page access token". But how to use it correctly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that. As always, an answer is finded actually after posting here...
I did the trick by **adding permission "status_update"** to my session, as said here:

[why does posting to facebook page yield "user hasn't authorized the application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application)

However, i didn't find any information about requiring this. Also, post to user's feed was successful without this permission.
Hope this will help somebody!