# Post to facebook fan page as a user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Can anyone tell me how to do this using php sdk.

I have using this code. This code was suppose to post to user's timeline as well as the fan page. The person who is logged in would be the one who is doing the post. So on the fan page 
this would have appeared under recent activity. However, now the code has stopped working saying that the user has not authorised the app. I do not understand why this could be happening.

```
  include("../php-sdk/facebook.php");

 /*START FACEBOOK lOGIN*/
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => Appid,
    'secret' => Appsecret,
    'cookie' => true
 ));


 $pageId = PageId;

$user= $facebook->getUser();
$newfbuser = 0;
if (!empty($user)) {

    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

   // $fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,status_update,publish_stream, manage_pages'
            ));
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();


      $param = array(
                'method' => 'users.getInfo',
                'uids' => $uid,
                'fields' => array('name','sex')
      );
    $users_getinfo = $facebook->api($param);


    $save['oauth_uid'] = $users_getinfo['0']['uid'];
     $save['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
    $save['facebook_email'] = $users_getinfo['0']['email'];   
    $save['name'] = $users_getinfo['0']['name'];   


  $link_url = "http://google.com";
   $pic = 'http://xxxxx/images/Testing.jpg';
    $attachment = array( 
    'access_token' =>$fb_access_token,
    'message' => 'This is a message by bob',
     'link' => 'http://xxxxx/');

   //      print_r($fb_access_token);

       echo 'on my timeline<br />';
   $facebook->api("/me/feed",'post',$attachment);  
   $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed",'post',$attachment);
        echo 'successfully posted';


   }
```

Comment: what error do you get? Try to catch exceptions and look at them...

Comment: Asking for permissions during login is done via the `scope` parameter – not the way old `req_perms` that has been outdated for almost forever now.

Comment: I am getting user is not authorised error.

Answer (score 1):

> // $fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
>       $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
>           'req_perms' => 'email,status_update,publish_stream, manage'
>               ));

No such thing call "**manage**", the correct permission was **manage_pages**

[image]

Comment: I have corrected mistake in the code there.. Do I need manage_pages to post as a fb user... Because I won't be posting as an admin here.

Comment: See my asnwer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application/15943045#15943045

Comment: Also, you can always debug your user access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and make sure it show the expected permissions.