# Post to Facebook timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Can anyone provide me the steps using an app to post using facebook php sdk on my timeline.

What permissions are needed?

I have already tried various methods. But it would be helpful if you'll can share any link which you'll found working for you'll.

I am facing issues with the post. With the error saying that that user has not authorised the app. However the user has authorised it.

Something with the access token is causing an issue which i cannot trace.

I have already posted my code but I haven't received much response there. 
[Post to facebook fan page as a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984317/post-to-facebook-fan-page-as-a-user)

---

Update: I was receiving error as I was using older version of php-sdk. changing it to the latest one, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should ask for the 'publish_stream' permission, here you can find a complete example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi

Comment: I have used publish_stream permission. But still i get an error.