# facebook graph Api: Posting on page: permission issue

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop a app which will post on user's Facebook page.

Steps I followed are:
1.Created a fb App, with permission : `manage_pages` and `publish_actions`

[image]

2.Redirected user to 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth

With parameters:

```
client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID
redirect_uri=FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL
scope=manage_pages,publish_actions
```

Where user allowed app against each permissions

[image]
[image]

3.On call back url (`FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL`), cought `CODE` sent by facebook api

4.Now I sent get request to `url = https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` with parameters:

```
'client_id':FACEBOOK_APP_ID
'redirect_uri':FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL
'client_secret':FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
'code':CODE
```

from respose sent by facebook, I filtered `TOKEN`

5.sent get request to url = `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts`. with parameters:

```
'access_token':TOKEN
```

from response I received, I saved page id as `PAGE_ID`, page_token as `PAGE_TOKEN`

6.I tried to post something on user's facebook page, I sent post request to url = `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed` , with parameters:

```
'access_token':TOKEN'
'message': MESSAGE_TEXT,
```

Snap! in response I received:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I couldn't figure out What mistake I am committing, Do I need to get my app reviewed before posting ? If yes, How can I test my app?

I also tried this by creating a test user. I got the same error.

Comment: just open the permission dialogue with the publish_action permission then update your access token and then post your message

Comment: This makes no sense, your user needs to approve you to post to their wall. If they only login they only grant you the most basic permissions exclusive of posting to their wall.

Comment: @dhana User deleted the the app from setting>apps, and reauthorized it, this made not any difference.

I edited the question and inserted screenshot.
How can I test the posting on wall functionality of the app? Thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application. It might be helpful

Comment: @dhana Thanks bud! `status_update` permission was not visible from app control panel, that's why I was sceptic. But sending this in scope parameter solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@dhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401736/dhana),

In order to Post on a facebook page, App need `manage_pages` and `publish_action` app centre permission, and  `manage_pages` , `publish_action` and `status_update` scope while requesting

```
url = https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?\
    client_id='+FACEBOOK_APP_ID+'&\
    redirect_uri=' +FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL+'&\
    scope=manage_pages,publish_actions,status_update
```