# window phone - The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm use sdk Facebook for windows phone([http://facebooksdk.net/),and](http://facebooksdk.net/%29,and) I want share status on facebook.I have code as below :

```
 var facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(fbAccessToken);

             var postParams = new
             {
                 message = message,
                 name = name,
                 caption = caption,
                 link = link,
                 picture = urlImg
             };

             try
             {

                 dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await facebookClient.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postParams);
                 var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;
                 flag = true;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 flag = false;
             }
```

Before a few day,It run normaly and have no problem.But now when I run my app,I get error "(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not added permission called **status_update**.

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application) Helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any `Permissions` so `Default Permission` Would be Provided to you. You are Missing Other `Permission for Status Update`. Try with Providing Permisssion and if that is not happening, You can Integrate Facebook to Your Windows Phone Application like [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application)