# cant set facebook permissions right

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API for Facebook and I'm trying to post something in a FB Group but i get a permission error that I can't solve. I tried giving permissions like I found online but it's not working. Can you please help?

```
$fb = new Facebook([
                    'app_id' => 'app_id',
                    'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
                    'default_access_token' => 'access_token', // optional

            ]);
            $permissions = ['publish_actions','manage_pages'];
            $fb->post('/page_id/feed');
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Is it a closed group? If so, you need admin access to be able to post into via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fb = new Facebook([
                'app_id' => 'app_id',
                'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
                'default_access_token' => 'access_token', // optional
                'scope'=>['publish_actions','manage_pages', 'status_update']
        ]);
$fb->post('/page_id/feed');
```

This should work.

Comment: it did work but now another showed up. this time: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action". thank you anyway

Comment: what did you try to do ? whom are you posting as ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application

Comment: @Sooraq I'm posting as the admin of the page

Comment: Maybe you are missing status_update scope, updated the answer.