# Facebook app permission request before using my app

Tags: facebook, permissions, request

I have made a simple quiz on my website: [click here](https://mywat.net/sts/) 
I also created facebook app. You can see on this page : [Click here](https://apps.facebook.com/ingilizceseviyetesti/) Before people use my application i want to ask them permission as others. How can i do it ? I am new and i do not know too many codes.

Comment: Yes i tried this but i could not do it.

Comment: Maybe some people here can help you if you gave more information about your code, which error you got, ...

Comment: I did not write any code.I just have the index.html in my hosting and this is it.

Comment: I dont know what to do exactly.

Comment: I found at least two other stackoverflow posts about facebook permissions, you can check them out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897056/when-to-request-permissions-with-facebooks-new-android-sdk-3-0

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432426/which-facebook-permissions-allow-for-posting-to-a-page-wall-not-profile-wall

Comment: I already check them but it did not work.