# Post on facebook SDK WP8

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action when post on facebook by through winows phone 8 code:

```
dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await instance.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", postParams);
```

permessions add in `session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream,publish_actions");`

Debug access token on facebook app display

**App ID -- User ID -- Issued 1409307661 Expires 1414491661 Valid True Origin Mobile Web Faceweb Scopes : public_profile**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `Permission` called `status_update`?

Perfect sample would be this:

[why does posting to facebook page yield "user hasn't authorized the application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/)

[Which Facebook permissions allow for posting to a page wall (not profile wall)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432426/)